# In Go how to get enum (const iota int) value when you have its name as a string

Tags: go, enums, type-conversion

I have a Golang "enum"

```
type MyType int 
const (
  Thing1 MyType = iota
  Thing2
  Thing3
)
```

Later, in a different go file/package, I have the names defined above as *strings*.

How do I go from *string* to *enum*? I know if MyType were string and not int, I could do

```
MyType(myString)
```

But it doesn't work on int (since myString is not an int)

Comment: You cannot. Your MyType values do not _have_ a name. If you want them to have one you have to provide your own code and names. There are tools for doing this, e.g. https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer

Comment: Its a good idea to also create a String() method that returns a string. Then built-in functions such as Printf() can convert it to a string automatically.

func (m MyType) String() string {
    return []string{"Thing1", "Thing2", "Thing3"}[m]
}

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to change the type of `MyType` You could define a mapping for your string to enum and use it like so:

```
type MyType int
const (
    Thing1 MyType = iota
    Thing2
    Thing3
)

var MyTypeMappings = map[string]MyType{
    "Thing1": Thing1,
    "Thing2": Thing2,
    "Thing3": Thing3,
}

func main() {
    myType := MyTypeMappings["Thing1"]
    fmt.Print(myType)
}
```